# Gremlin : What is the most efficient way to write multiple traversals?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Suppose I have a vertex person, and it has multiple edges, I want to project properties from all traversal. What is the most efficient way to write a query in Cosmos DB Gremlin API?

I tried the following, but its performance is slow.

```
g.V().
hasLabel('person').
project('Name', 'Language', 'Address').
by('name').
by(out('speaks').values('language')).
by(out('residesAt').values('city'))
```

Also, I have multiple filters and sorting for each traversal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can write that specific traversal as you've shown it any more efficiently than it is already written, especially if you've added filters to the `out('speaks')` and `out('residesAt')` traversals to further limit those paths and as it stands in your example you only return the first "language" or "city" found which is obviously faster than traversing all of those possible paths.

It does stand out to me that you are trying to retrieve all the "person" vertices. You don't say that you have additional filters there specifically, but if you do not then the cost of this traversal could be steep if you have millions of "person" vertices coming back. Typically, traversals that only filter on a vertex label will be costly as most graphs do not optimize those sorts of lookups. In the worst case, such a situation could mean that you have to do a full graph scan to get that initial set of vertices.